# How to reserve bytes in code segment in 8086

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm wondering if there's any way to reserve more bytes for code segment (specifically 256), because I need to have all segments at least 256 bytes long and I need to store data in all of them. I tried resb that works for all other segments but that doesn't seem to work for cs.

Comment: *I need to have all segments at least 256 bytes long*.  This statement doesn't make sense.  Segments are not variable length.  Did you mean section here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the BSS section you can use `RESB`, `RESW`, ...

In the DATA section you can use `DB`, `DW`, ...

In the CODE section you normally just write instructions, but you can also use `DB`, `DW`, ...
Accessing this data would require using a segment override prefix like in `mov ax, [cs:bx]`.

Additionally you can use the `ALIGN` macro both in CODE and DATA sections.

Say your CODE section only contains the one instruction `RET` and you let it follow by `ALIGN 256`, then the new CODE section will have 256 bytes: 1 time `RET` and 255 times `NOP`.